# Got no real answers to my bounty question, but the bounty was auto-awarded to a non-answer

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I had a question with 100 bounty that had one answer - and it was a complete non-answer.

I was pretty shocked to see this answer got the bounty automatically.   Is there a way to prevent this?

edit:

It is entirely possible to game the bounty system.  Just wait for questions without answers that are about to expire, add some BS answer and have two sockpuppets upvote your answer.

Comment: To get auto-awarded, an answer must be upvoted... so it can't have been **that** much of a non-answer...

Comment: For an answer to be automatically awarded a bounty, it must have a score of two or more. Unless it already has a score of three or more, you can prevent it by diwnvoting the answer, because that might bring it below the required score to get automatically awarded the bounty. Other than that, I'm afiad there isn't much you can do to prevent that.

Comment: @Catija it was asking for clarification, something more suitable for a comment.

Comment: If that's really the case, how did it get a score of +2 and survive on the site without getting deleted as NAA? This one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760859/is-it-possible-to-obtain-a-jwt-refresh-token-using-my-server-as-sort-of-a-proxy ?

Comment: Vote fraud is taken pretty seriously, so if someone actually tries to game the system like that, it might not go too well for them. Unfortunately I don't think the bounties they managed to snag before getting caught could be reversed, though. That said, it looks like the answer here came way before the bounty expired.

Comment: @Jefromi: Mods can remove (and even refund) bounties if they really need to, and vote fraud is an excellent case for that to apply.

Comment: @adapt-dev: That answer in particular was a bit sketchy, but there's no reason to delete it: it *does* seem to contain a perfectly plausible suggestion sandwiched between two requests for clarification. But just because an answer *contains* a link, or a comment, or whatever, doesn't mean the whole thing should be deleted unless that's all it is.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I am a mod - I know where the menu option is to remove an ongoing bounty, but can't find one for already awarded bounties. It's possible I'm missing something, but I really thought mods didn't have that power. Maybe CMs do? Or do you know for a fact mods can do it?

Comment: @Jefromi: Hmm. I may be thinking of CMs, but perhaps the functionality is hidden somewhere.

Comment: @Jefromi - If a bountied answer is deleted, the bounty is removed from the recipient, but not refunded. There's no way to refund a bounty after it has been awarded or has expired.

Comment: Also, I see no indication of voting fraud involving the answer in question. Any question that has a late-stage bounty gets a lot of views, which can mean many votes for the questions and answers, if the answers even seem reasonable. I think that's all that happened here. If we do catch someone using puppets or voting rings to snipe bounties, we usually delete the answer to remove the bounty and suspend the user involved for a while (not to mention removing the puppets and invalidating any ring). That's not the case here, though.

Comment: @BradLarson I didn't claim there was fraud here.  I said it was very easy though with the current auto-bounty.

Comment: I think they should make it so that if the user who put the bounty on the question downvotes a certain answer, that answer is not eligible for being arwarded half the bounty automatically.